# Flat and crispy shading

Tags: unity, graphics, shading

Im trying to create a mobile game that has flat, bright colors and I want every place to be lightened the same. Like this game:
[image]

and this is my game's current state:
[image]

I don't know what the problem is. It is too dark and not as good-looking as the first image. If i increase the light, it gets bright, not saturated and crispy. Maybe wrong lighting or wrong material usage? First image looks so crispy and it almost like a Vector art. I modeled all of the assets myself in Blender. I tried using Ambient lighting but it didn't work. I also turned off shadows but still the same.
Also there is a distortion in the big red circle i drew and i don't know why is it hapening. And i don't want the shiny light in the little red circle.

Comment: Sounds like you should probably just ditch lighting and use unlit shaders with pastel colored textures. You could then tweak the color setttings or even fake lighting with post processing. That would let you use simple flat colors, while also being able to modify colors for day/night cycles.

Answer (score 1):

In the Mesh Renderer component you can select if that object will cast and receive shadows. So if there are some 3D objects that you don't want to have a shadow, just disable **Shadow Casting** and **Shadow Receiving** in the chosen model’s Mesh Renderer component. (I found that from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-disable-shadows-per-gameobject.314495/).)

Additionally, you may want to increase the ambient lighting and decrease the directional light intensity, which means the light is technically everywhere and will give you the cartoon effect that is desired.

Comment: If you disable shadows, wouldn't the object still have specular highlight? Feels like OP also only wants diffuse lighting